# Dropwizard interceptor response status

Tags: java, interceptor, dropwizard

I implemented interceptor in my microservice which is based on dropwizrd version 0.9.
I need interceptor because I need to look into entity of every response.

Example:

```
public class myInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext writerInterceptorContext) {
        doSomething(writerInterceptorContext);
        writerInterceptorContext.proceed();
    }
}
```

It works great, but I have an issue, I need to know status code of a response (Ex.: 200, 204, 500, 404). There is no status in `writerInterceptorContext`, how can I retrieve the status in the interceptor?

Thank you.

Comment: Kind of a workaround but you can make a `ContainerResponseFilter` and use `requestContext.setProperty("status", responseContext.getStatus())`. Then in the interceptor just get it with `context.getProperty("status")`

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, thank you. I wonder, would it be easier to convert interceptor to filter?

Comment: You can get the entity in a ContainerResponseFilter. Just use `responseContext.getEntity()`